# How to improve upload speed of files to google storage?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client, pre-signed-url

I have implemented javascript code to upload files in multiple chunks to google cloud storage.

Below is flow that I execute the upload file:
1. user selects a file to upload using javascript client web app {request is from ASIA region}
2. javascript client app request to our app server implemented in NODEJS  {hosted in google cloud's compute engine - US region} to allow the file upload {authorization}
2. Nodejs App server returns a signedurl to the client app
3. client app start uploading file to google storage in multiple chunks using that signed url
4. on upload successful client reports to app server

I am able to upload files in multiple chunks, **but I have observed that upload is 2-3 times slower if I host nodejs app server in google cloud US region rather than hosting on same machine from where I am executing client app request**

Please let me know if you have solution how to improve the upload performance.

There is some workaround mentioned in [google cloud signed-url documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) :

> Resumable uploads are pinned in the region they start in. For example,
>   if you create a resumable upload URL in the US and give it to a client
>   in Asia, the upload still goes through the US. Performing a resumable
>   upload in a region where it wasn't initiated can cause slow uploads.
>   To avoid this, you can have the initial POST request constructed and
>   signed by the server, but then give the signed URL to the client so
>   that the upload is initiated from their location. Once initiated, the
>   client can use the resulting session URI normally to make PUT requests
>   that do not need to be signed.

But with that reference:

1. I couldnt found any code sample for: once client receives the signed
   url from server how the initial JSON API call can be constructed ??
2. what should be expected response in 1st call? and how to extract
   session URI
3. how to use the session URI to upload further chunks?

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing two separate GCS features. GCS allows for resumable uploads to be authorized to third parties without credentials in a couple of ways.

First, and preferred, is signed URLs. Your sends a signed URL to a client that will allow that client to begin a resumable upload.

Second, and less preferred due to the region pinning you mention above, is having the server initiate a resumable upload itself and then passes the upload ID to the client.

It sounds like you want the first thing but are using the second.

Using signed URLs requires making use of the XML API, which handles resumable uploads in a similar way to the JSON API: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload

You'll want to sign that very first POST call to create an upload and pass that URL to the user to invoke on their own.